# Is there a way to download applications from the Android market for offline installation?

Tags: google-play-store, uninstallation, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download apk file on PC from market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-to-download-apk-file-on-pc-from-market)

Is there a way to download an Android installation package from the market so that it can be installed offline at a later time (e.g. from an SD card)? This might be useful for backing up applications so you don't have to search for and download them all again. It could also be useful setting up multiple devices or just sharing an application with a friend in an area without network access.

Answer (score 2):

Using backup applications such as Titanium Backup do this exactly. They basically extract the .apk (installer) and back it up to the SD card. Then, when you 'restore' using Titanium Backup, you can select which apps you want to restore and it will reinstall them using the backed up .apk.