# Can I download Android apps to a computer and then transfer to my phone

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download APK file on PC from Market?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-to-download-apk-file-on-pc-from-market)

I'm wondering if I can download Android apps to my computer then transfer to a phone because I don't have a wifi connection on my phone to download.

Comment: Yes. you. can do it.

Comment: If your device has Gogle Market installed you could try share an internet connection of your PC via USB (Reverse USB Tethering)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you can - there are a number of ways - via ADB and pushing it.

A simpler way would be to either connect your device via USB to your PC and copy over the android APK files to a folder on your SD card (either internal or external on your device).

Using a file explorer like ASTRO, Estrongs or some other one of choice, you can then navigate to the folder where you placed those APKs and click on them to install.

Prior to this, you ought to enable the option ALLOW INSTALLATION FROM UNKNOWN SOURCES in ANDROID SETTINGS > APPLICATIONS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what this user is actually asking is if he can download apps from "Market" to his computer and them pass them to the android device.

Currently I don't know how to do it, and what is more, market does not allow you to download or push apps to devices that are not listed as compatible with the app, and this is annoying because there are a lot of tablets that are not the the list.