# Download Google Play Apps from Computer?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-android-market)

Can I not download the Google Play Android apps first in my computer and then transfer it to my mobile and then install and use it?

Answer (score 3):

Afraid you cannot do that as that is violating the [Terms and Conditions](http://play.google.com/intl/en/about/terms.html) of Google Play.

> 3.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) Google Play by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) Google Play through any automated means (including use of scripts, crawlers, or similar technologies) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Google Play website.

Comment: but I am not doing any automated work.

Comment: play.google.com opens in my web browser in my computer, I see the details of app, and I want to download it.

Comment: Its not about 'doing any automated work', its about being able to pull down the apks without using Google Play which is what you're asking for!