# How do I download app's APK file from Market to my desktop computer?

Tags: applications, downloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-play-store)

Is there any working tool I could use to download app's APK file from Market to my desktop computer?

I know there was a Chrome extension but it no longer works.

Comment: See this, and note what was stated in the terms & conditions as per my answer, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25430/download-google-play-apps-from-computer/25431#25431

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is against terms and conditions to do so.  But if you would still like to do so, a work around is to use an emulator and connect to market.  [This](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html) site explains how it can be done.

Once such emulator is working you can use applications like [app extractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sylark.apkextractor&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC5zeWxhcmsuYXBrZXh0cmFjdG9yIl0.) to extract the APK to emulator's file system (sd card). Then you can use adb pull command to take it out.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's not intended for several reasons (at least one of them was why that Chrome extension got modified in the first place). Installation from "the Market" (now known as "Playstore") should be done via the install process. Ideally, the user shall have no access to the `.apk` file at all (to prevent de-assembling etc., or pirating payed apps).

A valid reason for requiring the "real `.apk` is e.g. when your device has no Market/Playstore app. In those cases, you might contact the developer and ask him for the `.apk`. Some even have it on their websites for free download. Also, if you report bugs or request new features, the developer might offer you a pre-release `.apk` for testing purposes.

But as to your original question: There is no official solution, and I don't know of any "inofficial way" for this.

Comment: Update: [you can do so](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/122286/16575) meanwhile – though of course not "officially" :)