# Download purchased APK from play store

Tags: google-play-store, apk, downloading, paid-apps

I am using CyanogenMod on my Android devices without Google Apps (and consequently without the Play Store). Nevertheless, I have a Google account bound to my device ID and have purchased various apps with the account.

I want to download the APK files of the purchased apps and install them via ADB. About a year ago that was no problem using Real APK Leech or the APK Downloader extension for Chrome. Today Real APK Leech is seemingly unable to download any APKs, and the Chrome extension can only download APK files of free apps, even though the used Google Account has purchased the apps.

Are there any currently working ways of downloading purchased APK files without using the Play Store-App on the device itself?

(Similar questions I found on this site suggest outdated answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities for this. One is using the appropriate counter-parts from the [µg project](https://github.com/microg) (pronounced "micro-G"; formerly known as [NOGAPPS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375)) – in this case [Phonesky](https://github.com/microg/Phonesky) (the inofficial Google PlayStore Client) or [BlankStore](https://github.com/mar-v-in/BlankStore/releases/) (same thing, basically). Each of these two would run directly on the device, no Google-Apps required (hence the name "NOGAPPS", or "micro-G(oogle)"). Check with [FakeGApps](https://github.com/thermatk/FakeGApps), which has a good ReadMe to get you started with that on a Google-free device.

[image: BlankStore]
<sup>*Blankstore* (source: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375); click for larger variant)</sup>

Then there's [Raccoon](https://github.com/onyxbits/Raccoon), available for Linux, Mac, and Windows, see the article [Raccoon is a desktop downloader for Google Play Store apps](http://androidcommunity.com/r-20141208/) at AndroidCommunity. *Raccoon* can be used on your computer to download the APKs, which you then would need to install by other means (`adb install`, or copy to your Android device and manually install there). *Raccoon* also keeps track of updates available for apps you "watch". I'm not sure if it can deal with apps already bought (didn't give it a try yet), but as it works with your normal GPlay credentials, it should. As with *BlankStore,* just the *process* of bying apps will not be available – but you can do *that* using the *Google Playstore* with your web browser.

[image: Raccoon]
<sup>*Raccoon* (source: [Tutonaut](http://www.tutonaut.de/apps-herunterladen-und-mehr-den-google-play-store-vom-desktop-aus-nutzen.html); click image for larger variant)</sup>

With payed apps, trouble often is they use Google's license service to verify their "legitimacy". That would fail with *Raccoon* if you've got neither GApps nor NOGAPPS on your device. *BlankStore* and *Phonesky*, on the other hand, were reported to take care of that as well (though I've experienced *BlankStore* to fail with payed apps recently, which might be caused by some API changes on Google's end – I didn't dig deeper into that yet, so I cannot tell for sure, but I [don't seem to be the only one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61863742&postcount=1101)).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Raccoon seems to be exactly what I have been looking for - it seems very mature and managed to download an already purchased app!

Comment: Glad I could help! Meanwhile found out [why BlankStore doesn't work anymore with paid apps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=48998852&postcount=495) But something seems to be pending, according to this commit: [Licensing working, building needs to be fixed](https://github.com/mar-v-in/BlankStore/commit/2ae2526afb366b7abf94bed3c59b6e761f4d6d0c) :)