# Where are the libraries/dependencies for an Android app stored on the file system?

Tags: applications, apk

I found a file path from [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

> `/data/app/<pkg>*/lib/<arch>/*.so` (shared libraries)

However, this only shows libraries for some apps.

Is there another location where shared libraries are stored for an app? If not, is there a way to find this information from the APK or such?

Note: I have root on my phone.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122280/download-purchased-apk-from-play-store

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate on how I would use this to find the libraries/dependencies?

Comment: that might be more of a StackOverflow question.  I just left as a comment because it's helpful.  Your best bet is a decompiler. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752446/how-to-decompile-an-android-app-from-the-google-play-store

Comment: I tried decompiling. Did not provide me with any useful info

Comment: you're going to have to read the source code.

Comment: Libs aren't extracted to that path if `extractNativeLibs=false` is set. Simply get the APK file and explore with any ZIP explorer, even without decompiling. Libraries are in `lib` directory. But if not being loaded by Android's dynamic linker/loader, apps can store native code in other locations too (e.g. `assets`, `raw`) and may extract to any path where they have write access. App's dependencies on OS native code are obviously already there on device in `/system/lib*` directories.