# Can Swype be downloaded from a PC and transfered to the phone by a USB cable?

Tags: swype

I'm trying to download the Swype installer to my PC so I can transfer it to my phone without using my data plan. When I go to the website and try to download the installer without registering I get the message

> Sorry! This is not an Android device. It appears you're not using an
>   Android device, so you cannot download the Swype Beta Installer.

Is there anything I can do?
Also why must you first install the Swype installer which installs Swype, it seems like an unescecary step? It sure is stupid that Swype can't be proper and just be in the market.

Comment: This generic question appears to cover this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-play-store

Comment: @AlEverett but Swype isn't in the play store so this is different.

Comment: Generally the same idea, however. You want to get an apk file from a location that's designed to only accept connections from Android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the direct download link to the Swype Installer APK: http://swypemedia.swype.com/beta-d1/media/installer/Swype-Installer-2.0.apk

You can access this from any device (including a desktop computer).

Swype uses the installer app for it's licensing system.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't your phone have WiFi? I'm interested to know which Android phone has no WiFi. If you go to the beta.swype website with your phone browser and use WiFi you should use no "data". If your service provider is charging you to use WiFi you need to jump that ship ASAP.

PS: If you want to be sure you aren't using "data", turn on Airplane Mode and then turn on WiFi. The "bars" will remain off, but you will be able to use WiFi. It's how I use my "phone" even though I have no service to save battery.

Comment: Seems like a poor answer. What if he had internet connection, but it was a wired connection, not WiFi.