# How can I Run/Download Android Apps on a PC?

Tags: applications

I tried running Android 4.1.1 in VirtualBox, but it was too slow and sluggish to do anything. I came across Windroy which runs Android as a Windows app, but it won't run Google Play.

I want to run this on my laptop.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330) seems relevant, but the fact that AIDE is a paid app might be a snag.

Comment: I don't have an Android anymore so idk what to put for Device ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Bluestacks has gone through a lot of new updates since the last time I used it. Wouldn't run on Windows 8, but fine on my Windows 7 laptop. Thank you!

Comment: No problem.. hope they fix the windows 8 compatibility issue soon.. glad it worked for you :)

Comment: or May be [Andy](http://www.andyroid.net/)?..it cliams it works well on windows 7/8

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz you could also try Phoenix OS or Remix OS.

Comment: Those didn't exist when I posted this. Gotta say I love Remix OS. It's really nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try [youwave](http://youwave.com/download.html) or [bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com), both works just fine and smooth too.