# The link APK Downloader is not working. Is there any other convenient method to download the APK file to my notebook?

Tags: google-play-store

The link APK Downloader is not working.

Is there any other convenient method to download the APK file to my notebook ?

Comment: Have you checked [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330/16575) for alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your phone/tablet doesn't have Google Play. To directly download apps why not use [Amazon Market](http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b/ref=topnav_storetab_mas?node=2350149011) to download apps from your phone.

Other than this, I'd recommend you to Google out individual apps by name for their APK or wait for the service to return.

Comment: Careful with "googling APKs". Or rather with downloading the results. Have a very, very, very close look at the source – as this is the best way to get malware (modified `.apk` files bringing "nice" XMas presents along) on your device! I rather discourage this. Instead, take a look at our [alternative-markets tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info) and [What are the alternative Android app markets?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/216/16575)

Comment: I'll second what Izzy is saying. I can't agree with this answer as long as the "recommend you to google ... apps" part stands. That's **dangerous advice**.