# Lifecycle and Compatibility of An Android Version (say 4.4.2)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I believe, currently Android 7.1.2 is the most updated version of android.

I searched more to understand the life cycle of an android version but I couldn’t find.

For example,

What would be the life cycle of Android 4.4.2 after which Android 4.4.2 will be incompatible to most android applications?

My android device is 4.4.2. I would like to know same for my device as well i.e. what would be the life cycle of Android 4.4.2 after which my device will be incompatible to most android applications.

These days, the compatibility information of most android applications is like 4.0+.

I believe I explained my doubt well.

With Regards

Tech Goal

Comment: With a few exceptions like if the play store stopped supporting something developers get to decide what OS versions are supported.

Comment: Also as a side note you can always [download the apk for that version of android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-play-store) and install even if the play store stopped supporting your version.  This does take foresight though.

Comment: The support cycles of well-known apps tend to be very, *very* long, to the extent average users don't need to worry about it. Remember, there are regions where smartphone development is way behind the rest of the world, and where Android 4.0 might still be the norm.