# How to successfully and safely install a free app, using android (not a PC), from Play Store but without using the Play Store app?

Tags: google-play-store

I log in on Google with Firefox, access the Play Store site, click "Install" for the chosen app (only clickable after I remove `&gl=US` from the URL). It says it will be installed soon. 30 nonsense minutes later, nothing happened, and the site says "installed". So, it simply doesn't work.

How to make it work?

I don't want Play Store app endless restarting, bloating my 1.4GB RAM, and making good games, on my old phone, lag, or even crash. I already disabled or uninstalled many other bloatware apps, this one I enable and disable all the time, so messy is my Android realm user experience. I found no .apk link thru Chrome's `view-source:` at the Play Store site.

Any other way to get a safe APK from the Play Store site without the Play Store app, can work as an answer too!

Someone suggested: [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-play-store)
by what i read, i could directly download from play store, but i would need a PC and java, and use my credentials on it, what i could do but would require a PC, so i edit my question.
I could also download from other sites mirroring apks, but my goal was directly from play store.

In truth... if the play store app could stop auto restarting (after i force stop it), using RAM, making the phone lag and messing when i try to play heavy games (that use a lot of RAM), it would work too. But they insist in preventing us from controlling when an app will auto restart, and that just makes me feel like i am using windows 95 again (as i use linux on pc since long time ago) where we can control almost nothing right? so i created this: [where is configured how an app will auto restart?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/238825/where-is-configured-how-an-app-will-auto-restart)

stuck with Android 6.0.1 (samsung wont uodate it) on a sm-j700m

Comment: The web version of the Play Store only sends a push trigger to the Play Store app to do the installation process. It's the same as pressing the "Install" button from the Play Store app. There is [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330/44325), but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Oh... so the answer is: it is impossible!  :). I will check that link thx!

Comment: *Any other way to get a safe APK from the Play Store site without the Play Store app, can work as an answer too!* -- there you go. https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/apk-downloader-v4/about-raccoon/#about-raccoon