# where is configured how an app will auto restart?

Tags: auto-start

For ex, i know several apps that i have stopped will auto restart exactly at 00:00h everyday, making it lag horribly or even crash any game i am playing, what severily degrades my android realm user experience.

Others will instantly restart like the nosy weather app.

Others start when wifi connects, when the screen still locked wakes up, like watzap and gmail.

but Others i cant guess, like the useless email server (as i use gmail app), or chrome, and a few others. I could still try to uninstall a few of these, but others are really useful and i dont want to.

If there could have a way to tweak this auto-android-messing feature, so that it could be suspended while i play games, my android realm user experience could greately improve and i would be happier again.

Any tips?

Android 6.0.1
sm-j700m

Comment: When an app instance is created is determined by Android and should base on events like battery state changed or something like that. Additionally apps can schedule events for themself so a certain action is getting executed at a certain time. For battery saving in idle mode Android my move those events forth or back in time and combine them so the system doesn't have to wake up that often. Not sure if this also happens if the device is not idle/sleeping. If it also happens this could explain the behavior you encountered at midnight.

Comment: What games are affected? Does your phone really meets the requirements for playing them? Especially that your device has only 1.5 GB RAM may be on of your problems if the game needs it's all.

Comment: Exactly, the game needs it all, and works great after i unbloat the phone by uninstalling many apps thru adb shell. So the real problem is not the hardware. I pkay AnimA and pubg mobil elite.

Comment: Good idea, i will try the battery saving mode (not the ultra), may lower the insistence!

Comment: Apps can schedule [background tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) in a number of ways. So they are awakened by the system whenever needed. Services (foreground and background), broadcast receivers, cloud messaging and widget providers are common examples. This answer may help stop apps running in background: [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526).

Comment: Prevent just autostart/restart (but still allow it jusr after reboot) would be great. But when i run: `adb shell appops set com.android.vending RUN_IN_BACKGROUND deny`; it will "error: unlnown operation string: RUN_IN_BACKGROUND", Edit: my version has it not https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-6.0.1_r81/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java

Comment: `RUN_IN_BACKGROUND` op was added in Nougat.