# Since when it is no longer possible to download APKs directly from Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, apk

As far as I could search [on the site](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/how-can-i-download-an-apk-file-from-the-play-store), this has always been the case. I could be totally wrong, but I remember being able to download directly from the "Android Market" back then (unless it was just my imagination).

Comment: I have been an Android user since 2013 (we are in 2022 now), and I know for sure that Play Store never provided a way to download APKs. It always installed the apps in the device.

Comment: Android Market was renamed to Play Store in March 2012, so your memories are pretty old if they are true (but there is at least one answer on the page you have linked from 2011 that also indicates that downloading is not possible without third party tools). I don't know when I started with Play Store but it was always pretty complicated to download APKs from it as it requires non-official tools that often stop working the next day.

Comment: I remember having a Galaxy S II at the time, where it has the bag log and it said "Market".

Comment: Yeah it was possible once upon a time, i was a really small kid back then but i remember doing it... vague memories, but yes.

Btw welcome back to the Android club.