# How to download raw files from Google Play Store using my account?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Suppose I want to download any apps from Google Play Store, but what I want is not "automatically installed" but instead, I will get output files directed to the choosen storage, for instance whether it's the internal storage or using an SD card.

So, basically, I'm expecting to be able to get the raw "apk" file or any other extensions if it's a bundled app that can be installed manually.

Also as I've mentioned in the title i.e. using my account, so if I join the beta system, I will still be able to enjoy the beta feature before anyone else and always receive the latest version and download the "apk" or "apks" file or whatever from Play Store.

Is that possible? Evozi doesn't work, I've tried that.

Comment: what the hell is evozi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play Store has no official interface for downloading apps to storage instead of directly installing it.

#### Backup app from device

The only workaround is to install an app and then copy the APK files using an app like [Amaze File manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager) (the built-in "App Manager" supports a backup functionality for apps). However this way has one major disadvantage: Modern apps consist of multiple APK files that allows to adapt the app to the device (CPU architecture, display density, language...). The backup will thus only contain the APK files that match your device. Compared to APKs files you can download from various app download pages like [apkmirror.com](https://www.apkmirror.com/) which often contain APK files for all architectures, display density and language.

#### Direct download from Play Store using third party programs

But there are unofficial tools which simulate an Android phone that has your selected Google account installed. One of those tools is [Raccoon4](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/) a Java program which has to be executed on a PC (does not work directly on Android). Registering a certain phone model with your account can work or not (Google is constantly changing something on backend side).

As Raccoon4 uses the configured Google account it might be possible to download even beta apps you are registered for, but I am not sure if anybody has ever tested this. So this will most likely only work if downloading beta software does not require using a special API on backend side.

See also this old question [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330/2241)